# NodeJS module mutler: "Error: Unexpected field" again

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use mutler in a simple exercise of learning nodejs. After I upload the file, get the "Unexpected filed" error. I tried everything it was written on this subject but I still cannot get rid of this error.

Here is my node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: 'tmp/'});
var type = upload.single('avatar');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "upload.html" );
})

app.post('/file_upload', type, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    })

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

The html file used for upload:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>File Uploading Form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
       <h3>Upload Profile:</h3>
       Select a file to upload: <br />

       <form action = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/file_upload" method = "POST" 
          enctype = "multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
          <br />
          <input type = "submit" value = "Upload File" />
       </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

And the error I get in the web browser after upload:

```
Error: Unexpected field
     at makeError (/home/mihai/nodejs/tutorial/node_modules/multer/lib/make-error.js:12:13)
     at wrappedFileFilter (/home/mihai/nodejs/tutorial/node_modules/multer/index.js:40:19)
     at Busboy.<anonymous> (/home/mihai/nodejs/tutorial/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:114:7)
     at emitMany (events.js:146:13)
     at Busboy.emit (events.js:223:7)
     at Busboy.emit (/home/mihai/nodejs/tutorial/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:38:33)
     at PartStream.<anonymous> (/home/mihai/nodejs/tutorial/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:213:13)
     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
     at PartStream.emit (events.js:210:7)
     at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (/home/mihai/nodejs/tutorial/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:51:16)
```

Can anybody tell me how to make it work? I have tried also on a Windows 7, with node v8.8.1 and get the same error.

Comment: Could you include the code/form you're using to make the request?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your error stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that `multer` encountered a file field in the request that it wasn't expecting.

You've told `multer` to expect a single field called `avatar`:

```
var type = upload.single('avatar');
```

Your file field is actually called `file`:

```
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
```

Change it to `avatar` and everything should work fine:

```
<input type="file" name="avatar" size="50" />
```